# adjusting page number when having both portrait and landscape pages in rmarkdown

Tags: r, landscape, kableextra

so I have an rmarkdown containing both portrait and landscape tables.
the page number in portrait pages are ok and at the bottom of tha page, but for landscape pages the page number does not fall at the bottom ( it's position does not change from portrait)
how can I manage page numbers when adding `landspace()` to a `kbl()` object